# Issue with CSS animation in Firefox

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a fiddle which is a replica of something in one of our products at work. It is working in Chrome and IE but not firefox and I've stared for a while and can't see any reason why not. I'm hoping that asking will cause a brainwave.

It seems to show as a transparent color in Firefox, the fiddle shows values in Chrome and IE.

Cheers,
J

http://jsfiddle.net/qb9unwmh/2/

```
body {
 background: #ff0000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-name: taskUrgent;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-name: taskUrgent;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-direction: alternate;
backface-visibility: hidden;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-name: taskUrgent;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes taskUrgent {
  0% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0, #8c0000 100%);
 }
100% {
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8c0000 0, #510000 100%);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes taskUrgent {
  0% {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0, #8c0000 100%);
  }
  100% {
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8c0000 0, #510000 100%);
   }
}

@keyframes taskUrgent {
   0% {
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000 0%, #8c0000 100%);
  }
  100% {
       background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8c0000 0%, #510000 100%);
  }
}
```

Comment: your Fiddle doesn't show any result

Comment: It does in Chrome :)